# DmlException:SELF_REFERENCE_FROM_TRIGGER

Tags: apex, trigger

I have Opportunity-lookup field on Opportunity (self),

Scenario:

1. Opportunity A if select Opportunity B using lookup then Opportunity B's same lookup field automatically populate with Opportunity A.

I tried to achieve this using trigger - before insert/update but its failing as:

```
System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 006G000000DHaBlIAL; first error: SELF_REFERENCE_FROM_TRIGGER, Object (id = 006G000000DHaBl) is currently in trigger Oppy_before_INSUPD, therefore it cannot recursively update itself: []
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are in before insert trigger you can't reference the record being inserted as it hasn't been inserted yet. There is no Id to be referenced.

So when Opportunity A is being inserted, it can have a reference to Opportunity B (assuming it isn't being inserted in the same transaction) as it will have an Id and be in the database.

Until Opportunity A has been inserted there is nothing for Opportunity B to reference.

You could potentially use an after update trigger to update the reference from Opportunity B to point back to Opportunity A. Be careful here with the potential to create an update loop if you keep trying to update the related records reference.

See also [Why do my Apex Triggers throw the error SELF_REFERENCE_FROM_TRIGGER?](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000005278&language=en_US)