# Self Reference From Trigger error - Recursive Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, roll-up-summary

I have two before Triggers, one on my Project object & the other on Opportunities.

The Project Trigger takes the value from the Project record's field `MPM4_BASE__Deadline__c` and copies it into the related Opportunity's field `Implementation_Revenue__c` & the Opportunity trigger copies the updated value from that field into the `Opportunity_Imp_Revenue_Com_Date__c` field of a record for junction object ProjectxOpp__c which relates Projects to Opportunities.

Lastly, the value from the ProjectxOpp__c's `Opportunity_Imp_Revenue_Com_Date__c` is rolled up, using a standard rollup field, to the Project record.

When I edit the `MPM4_BASE__Deadline__c` field on the Project record, it causes an error

> execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. SELF_REFERENCE_FROM_TRIGGER, Object (id = a5E7000000008zR) is currently in trigger WE_IMProjCmpltnUp, therefore it cannot recursively update itself: [] Trigger.WE_ProjxOppUp: line 61, column 1: []: Trigger.WE_IMProjCmpltnUp: line 55, column 1.

Line 61 for Trigger WE_ProjxOppUp is `update juncRecs;` & line 55 for Trigger WE_IMProjCmpltnUp is `update updOpps;`.

I've seen [several](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/15826/self-reference-from-trigger-error-when-updating-child-record), [posts](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/31866/dmlexceptionself-reference-from-trigger) about the error & the [knowledge article](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000005278&language=en_US) but none seem to explain the cause of my error. Can anyone see a potential cause?

```
trigger WE_IMProjCmpltnUp on MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Project__c (before insert, before update) {


//section of code removed, creates validRecordTypeIds list

    Set<Id> projects = new Set<Id>();
    Map<Id,Date> deadlineDates = new Map<Id,Date>();
    List<Opportunity> updOpps = new List<Opportunity>();

    If(Trigger.isInsert){
        for(MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Project__c p : Trigger.new){
            if(validRecordTypeIds.contains(p.RecordTypeId) && p.MPM4_BASE__Deadline__c != null)
            {
                projects.add(p.Id);
                deadlineDates.put(p.Id, p.MPM4_BASE__Deadline__c);
            }
        }
    }

    If(Trigger.isUpdate){
                for(MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Project__c p : Trigger.new){
                    if(validRecordTypeIds.contains(p.RecordTypeId) && p.MPM4_BASE__Deadline__c != null)
                    {
                        MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Project__c oldP = Trigger.oldMap.get(p.Id);

                        if(oldP.MPM4_BASE__Deadline__c != p.MPM4_BASE__Deadline__c){
                            projects.add(p.Id);
                            deadlineDates.put(p.Id, p.MPM4_BASE__Deadline__c);
                        }
                    }
                }
    }

    if(projects.size() > 0){

        for(ProjectxOpp__c junc : [SELECT Project__c, Opportunity__r.Implementation_Revenue__c FROM ProjectxOpp__c
                                    WHERE Project__c In :projects])
        {
            Opportunity o = junc.Opportunity__r;
            Date newCompDate =  deadlineDates.get(junc.Project__c);
            if(newCompDate > o.Implementation_Revenue__c){
                o.Implementation_Revenue__c = newCompDate;
            }
            updOpps.add(o);
        }
        update updOpps;
    }
}
```

---

```
trigger WE_ProjxOppUp on Opportunity (before update) {

//section of code removed, creates validRecordTypeIds list

    Set<Id> opps = new Set<Id>();
    Map<Id,Date> oppCls = new Map<Id,Date>();
    Map<Id,Decimal> oppNetFSR = new Map<Id,Decimal>();
    Map<Id,Date> oppImpCom = new Map<Id,Date>();
    List<ProjectxOpp__c> juncRecs = new List<ProjectxOpp__c>();

    for(Opportunity o : Trigger.New){
        if(validRecordTypeIds.contains(o.RecordTypeId)){
            Opportunity oldO = Trigger.oldMap.get(o.Id);

            if(oldO.CloseDate != o.CloseDate){
                opps.add(o.Id);
                oppCls.put(o.Id, o.CloseDate);
            }
            if(oldO.Net_Full_Service_Revenue__c != o.Net_Full_Service_Revenue__c){
                opps.add(o.Id);
                oppNetFSR.put(o.Id, o.Net_Full_Service_Revenue__c);
            }               
             if(oldO.Implementation_Revenue__c != o.Implementation_Revenue__c){
                 opps.add(o.Id);
                 oppImpCom.put(o.Id, o.Implementation_Revenue__c);
             }
        }
    }

    if(opps.size() > 0){

        for(ProjectxOpp__c junc : [SELECT Opportunity__c, Opportunity_Net_FSR__c, Opportunity_Close_Date__c, Opportunity_Imp_Revenue_Com_Date__c FROM ProjectxOpp__c
                                    WHERE Opportunity__c IN :opps])
        {
            Date clsDt = oppCls.get(junc.Opportunity__c);
            if(clsDt != null){
                junc.Opportunity_Close_Date__c = clsDt;
            }
            Decimal netFSR = oppNetFSR.get(junc.Opportunity__c);
            if(clsDt != null){
                junc.Opportunity_Net_FSR__c = netFSR;
            }
            Date impRevComDt = oppImpCom.get(junc.Opportunity__c);
            if(impRevComDt != null){
                junc.Opportunity_Imp_Revenue_Com_Date__c = impRevComDt;
            }
            juncRecs.add(junc);
        }
        update juncRecs;
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any trigger or some other operation (flow / process) on the junction object ProjectxOpp__c that's updating back the milestone project ?

Comment: @VamsiKrishna thanks for the suggestion, there's no workflows, flows, processes or triggers for the ProjectxOpp__c object at all.

Comment: @VamsiKrishna but just to be clear, the object that's being referred to as a5E7000000008zR in the error message is the Project.

Comment: @VamsiKrishna I've just posted the resolution for my issue, I'd be interested to hear your thoughts on why changing the context of my Trigger from `before` to `after` has solved the issue because I have no idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of the issue was my `Project` roll-up fields, which were rolling up values from the `ProjxOpp` junction object and [would have](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1783/what-sobject-properties-dont-cause-triggers-to-fire) caused the triggers on the `Project` to execute again.

But interestingly, in this instance Salesforce seems to have been anticipating the roll-ups causing the second `Project` save procedure because the `Project` triggers didn't appear in my my debug logs a second time, before the error occurred.

Since my `WE_IMProjCmpltnUp` Trigger isn't updating the `Project`object, I was able to change it's execution to `after insert, after update` and this prevents the error from occurring.
This is because you can't update a record [from within it's Before trigger](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_calls_concepts_core_data_objects.htm), even though the roll-up actually causes the recalculation in the [After context](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm).
Again, it looks like this is Salesforce anticipating the change but not taking into account the context, when that change will be made.

Note - it wasn't necessary to also change the `WE_ProjxOppUp` Trigger to `after update` & doing that but not changing `WE_IMProjCmpltnUp` does not solve the issue.

Applying the solution from the Salesforce Knowledge Article on this topic - [How to avoid Recursive trigger](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000133752&language=en_US) - which also seems to have been proposed in this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/66321/10720) didn't solve my issue.

Comment: Did you get to understand the issue conceptually? I ran in to the same issue today and changing the context from `before` to `after` solved my problem too.

Comment: @sam_s I'm pretty new to development and I'm not absolutely sure that "Salesforce anticipating the roll-up calculation" is correct, to be honest but this is still my best guess at the reason for the issue & as you say, the solution works. If you spot anything that suggests another cause of the problem, please do let me know though!